# why does np.dot produce an attribute error which I just copied from a book?

Tags: numpy, google-colaboratory

I copied code from the book: neural network from scratch and somehow this produces an error.

```
import numpy as np

inputs = [1.0, 2.0, 3.0, 2.5]
weights = [0.2, 0.8, -0.5, 1.0]
bias = 2.0

outputs = np.dot(weights, inputs) + bias

print(outputs)
```

In the book this should prints 4.8, but my google colab says "'list' object has no attribute 'astype'" (line 7). Why does this happen?

https://ibb.co/nBTyLCm

Comment: same code works for me, try to restart your notebook and try again

Comment: @erentknn https://ibb.co/nBTyLCm

Comment: it's not the same but you can use np.array instead, i dont know why this code produces error

Comment: np.array produces 4.799999, not 4.8 but thanks for comments

Comment: works fine for me, Win10, Python 3.7, Spyder IDE

Comment: The problem seems to be tied to `nnfs`. It intercepts the call to `np.dot` and expects the passed object to be a numpy array.

Comment: While `numpy` functions usually try to convert their inputs to arrays, it's a good idea to get in the habit of do so yourself.  `inputs = np.array([1,2,3,5])` etc.   Especially if you want to ask SO questions.  If your question ambiguously describes a variable as array/list, the answers also like to be confusing.